# Image upload button not showing in magento WYSIWYG editor for limited access users

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 1.9 we have two types or users

1. Administrator
2. Content Manager

Administrator user has full rights whereas content manager users have limited access. Now if a content manager user want to add image in product description using wysiwyg then there is no image upload/browse option.
But for the administrator user who has full access can see the image upload/browse button in wysiwyg editor.
Please check the following screenshots for better understanding
[image: Administrator user view]

[image: Content Manager User]

Please help me to show image upload button in product description wysiwyg editor for limited access users as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide below access in your user role Resources

```
CMS -> Media Gallery
```

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you so much @Dhaval